# How can find the Etag in a DevOps Wiki Page using C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wiki

I need to update pages in my project Wiki on DevOps. I am using `C#` but in spite of trying out tons of examples from the DevOps APi documentation and other google searches,i can not find a way.

I can display a page using the Url [https://dev.azure.com/{company}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{identifier}/pages?path=/Home/App-Versions&api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Bcompany%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wiki/wikis/%7Bidentifier%7D/pages?path=/Home/App-Versions&api-version=7.0)

but i need to change the content using a PUT request. Anybody available to assist me ?

Comment: What's the problem? What did you try? The docs actually show how to get the eTag in the [Get Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get-page?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#get-page-as-json) example, and PUT is used in the [Create or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) example. PATCH is used to just update. The Etag is a response header.

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for reacting. I have tried all of the examples but i did not suceed. My communication with devops for all other kinds of info (both retreiving and creating tasks, features,userstories , works fine, but with wiki i keep getting authorisation errors or if i do get a successfull response to a request it does not contain any expected data.